# Is SO Saying that Chuck Yeager was a Secret Soviet?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

So I love the hats and all, especially my Chuck Yeager "secret" hat (though I still don't know what it was for (Update: now I think I know)).

And I'm not complaining or anything, but shouldn't the star be blue or something?

[image]

Because to military folks like General Yeager a single red star on a white background definitely means something other than a proud son of the good ole' U.S. of A.

[image]

Or is there some kind of secret message there too?

Comment: http://dundundun.net/

Comment: You *dare* question the Yeager?

Comment: @NickCraver Gosh, no, he's one of my heroes.  I *might* be questioning the message though ...  :-)

Comment: You got the Chuck Yeager hat because you ■■■■■■■■ ■ ■■■■■■■■ ■■ ■■■■ ■■■■ ■■ ■■■■■■■ *INFORMATION REDACTED CLASSIFICATION: TOP SECRET*

Comment: That hat _really_ fits you. I'm just sayin'

Comment: @TinyTim Yeah really, right?  It hits the nose almost perfectly.

Comment: Off topic: belongs on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Pëkka Another one for you conspiracy nuts: [If Community isn't a person, how can it wear hat(s)??](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a conspiracy.

Comment: I have clarified the title slightly for those who either are not reading the contents, or do not appreciate the *somewhat* whimsical nature of the Winter Bash and the Hats.

Comment: Nothing whimsical about a google result with a title implying Yeager is somehow associated with being a Soviet. Jingle bells, sleighs, and funny hats aside, that is messed up and if you had any sort of respect for the man you would not have that implication in your title.

Comment: @TravisJ, et. al.: If you read the question carefully you will note that no such claim is made by me, nor is any conspiracy involving the great General Yeager implied by me. I am questioning whether the hat should be colored as it is because *others* less able to read either nuance or whimsy might *infer* such a claim by StackExchange.

Comment: I disagree. The title is sensationalist to try to garner attention at the expense of Yeager. You may make the claim in the post which doesn't show up directly. As shown in an answer, the image is Chinese. Moreover, the US (via Yeager) worked with China in Pakistan during the cold war to fight against Russia who was working with India. So no, he was not a "secret soviet", and SE is also not implying it. The only person who even mentioned it, was you.

Comment: Sorry, I do whatever Leader Dearest tells me to.

Comment: Deep down, I think we all knew that *eventually*, the decision to go with a color-blind designer would come back to bite us.

Comment: And there's the "**42**"!  Woo hoo!

Comment: Did somebody mention my name?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To directly answer your question: No, they're not trying to imply he was secretly working for the Soviets.

[They're implying he was working for the Chinese.](https://www.google.com/search?q=chinese+fighter+pilot&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=4iKvUoL1N8e-kQeJ6YDIBA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=924)

Comment: See, I already had my reservations about [outsourcing the hats](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1677808#1677808) ...

Comment: whooooooooooooooooooooooooooops.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, I just now earned a Chuck Yeager hat on Meta, which I can only assume came from this post.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Hmm, that could have something to do with it.

Comment: No but seriously, the man is an American hero - can we re-color the star please?

Comment: @AdamRackis Are you saying [California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_California.svg) is un-American??!?1one

Comment: @SevenSidedDie According to many Texans, California **is** un-American.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Cool, Cascadia will take them then.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - yikes.  I think you got me.  I didn't even think of the CA flag since I'm from the correct, errr, east coast of the country :-)

Comment: Maybe we can figure out the secret to the hat. I believe I was awarded the had due to answering this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660131/different-default-pages-controllers-for-every-role-type-mvc-5/20660344#20660344

Answer (score 19):

Everyone knows that painting something red makes it go faster.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know for sure, but I'm assuming this is one of the source images our designer worked off of:

[image]

If only Yeager had flown in the days of color photography. Somebody travel back in time and settle this argument for real!

(Apparently, this headgear is [a tank corpsman's helmet on top of a leather aviator's cap](http://www.chuckyeager.com/1945-1947-mach-buster).)

Comment: I have neither a color picture of a similar helmet nor a TARDIS, but the device on then-Captain Yeager's helmet in this photo appears to be [the roundel of the United States Air Force](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Roundel_of_the_USAF.svg), which includes not a red star but a white one.

Answer (score 11):

I will say, figuring out why you earned this hat might present you with a ***very bright*** opportunity. Or you could wait, all will be revealed in the end ....

Comment: My guess: a *very quick* answer?

Comment: @Pëkka Nope. ***Buzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz*** (well, actually, sorda ...)

Comment: @Pëkka  That's what I thought at first too.  But fast answers are definitely not my forte', and I sure haven't had any today.  Fast *comments* on the other hand ... hmmm ...

Comment: Well, it's not getting the Enlightened badge, so my alternate guess would be that it's when someone favourites your question.

Comment: I am absolutely certain that it's answer-related.  I got it for an answer that gained 5 upvotes and no downvotes on meta.  I don't know if speed had anything to do with it.  Presumably there's some sort of "the right stuff" thing going on.

Comment: modification to the last - it might be off of points earned in a day or something similar.

Comment: Waiting till the end is no fun!

Comment: I'd agree with @JoeW! unleash the bots to find this out!

Comment: @BenBarden at least it is not about posting a question, because I have that hat on SO, and I have never asked a single question on SO so far (and I like it that way). Also my most recent (at the moment of writing) answer with 5 or more votes is from October. [It may be about editing, though]

Comment: So basically, if we figure out Yaeger then we get Eureka? I'm pretty certain Eureka is awarded by devs. As far as I can tell, Yaeger is for outscoring the accepted answer or some such.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that Mr. Peanut may have it.  This *is* something that I do all the time (edit/improve my posts, even after they're accepted).

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish Well, you figured out how _one_ of the hats work.

Comment: @TinyTim Yay! So figuring out how you get the hat gets you the hat? Isn't that a bit circular? :P

Comment: I was struggling with that one Manish - got two Yeagers on different sites before figuring it out - bit of trial and error with rapid answers/edits in and outside grace period/watching votes. In terms of Eureka moments, I like the idea that devs can award it for knowing that devs can award it (he hinted to @TinyTim :-)

Comment: I havent got the Yeager yet (simply because I dont go chasing hats), but it is pretty clear what its for (not gonna say it here though, SPOILERS). The Eureka is also clear! Just need to bribe one of the devs (with secrets, of course)... There is always at least one manual hat for figuring it out.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with employing Firebug chicanery to flag a question for migration to a site that's not listed in the "migrate this question to..." dialog? (Does that even work?)

Comment: @TinyTim Ah, so Eureka is for finding out how you get a hat! I was wondering how I got that :P now I hate you because I can't decide whether to wear ghost of winterbash past or eureka... :P

Comment: @AaronMiller: no, I've never done that.

Comment: I think you have to edit your answer before the 5 minute grace period expires...

Answer (score 5):

Is somebody dragging my name through the mud?
Why is he wearing my hat?

Comment: You're getting old, Chuck. You forgot how to spell your name.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Lol, I was thinking of the bomb!

Comment: You can't fool us [vascowhite](http://stackoverflow.com/users/212940/vascowhite).

Comment: @TheGrinch Darn it! Is it because my hat doesn't fit my Landrover Mr Harvey?